# Reversing WAV files, "An error occurred while opening the audio file"

Tags: c, audio, reverse, cs50, wav

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "wav.h"

bool check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Only put in the name of the original file, and the name of a new reversed file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2
    FILE *raw_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (raw_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open original file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read header
    // TODO #3

    WAVHEADER header;
    //4 bytes
    fread(header.chunkID, 1, 4, raw_file);
    //1 dword
    fread(&header.chunkSize, 4, 1, raw_file);
    //4 bytes
    fread(header.format, 1, 4, raw_file);
    //4 bytes
    fread(header.subchunk1ID, 1, 4, raw_file);
    //1 dword
    fread(&header.subchunk1Size, 4, 1, raw_file);
    //1 word
    fread(&header.audioFormat, 2, 1, raw_file);
    //1 word
    fread(&header.numChannels, 2, 1, raw_file);
    //1 dword
    fread(&header.sampleRate, 4, 1, raw_file);
    //1 dword
    fread(&header.byteRate, 4, 1, raw_file);
    //1 word
    fread(&header.blockAlign, 2, 1, raw_file);
    //1 word
    fread(&header.bitsPerSample, 2, 1, raw_file);
    //4 bytes
    fread(header.subchunk2ID, 1, 4, raw_file);
    //1 dword
    fread(&header.subchunkSize, 4, 1, raw_file);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4
    if (check_format(header) == false)
    {
        printf("Only works with wav files. Sorry!\n");
    }
    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5
    FILE *new_file = fopen(argv[2], "a");
    if (new_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open original file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(header.chunkID, 1, 4, new_file);
    //1 dword
    fwrite(&header.chunkSize, 4, 1, new_file);
    //4 bytes
    fwrite(header.format, 1, 4, new_file);
    //4 bytes
    fwrite(header.subchunk1ID, 1, 4, new_file);
    //1 dword
    fwrite(&header.subchunk1Size, 4, 1, new_file);
    //1 word
    fwrite(&header.audioFormat, 2, 1, new_file);
    //1 word
    fwrite(&header.numChannels, 2, 1, new_file);
    //1 dword
    fwrite(&header.sampleRate, 4, 1, new_file);
    //1 dword
    fwrite(&header.byteRate, 4, 1, new_file);
    //1 word
    fwrite(&header.blockAlign, 2, 1, new_file);
    //1 word
    fwrite(&header.bitsPerSample, 2, 1, new_file);
    //4 bytes
    fwrite(header.subchunk2ID, 1, 4, new_file);
    //1 dword
    fwrite(&header.subchunk2Size, 4, 1, new_file);
    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int block_size = get_block_size(header);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8
    BYTE buffer[block_size];
    while (fread(buffer, block_size, 1, raw_file) == 1)
    {
        fseek(new_file, 44, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(buffer, block_size, 1, new_file);
    }
    fclose(raw_file);
    fclose(new_file);
}

bool check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    if (header.format[0] == 'W' && header.format[1] == 'A' && header.format[2] == 'V' && header.format[3] == 'E')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    return header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8);
}
```

When the code runs, All I'm left with is the phrase "An error occurred while opening the audio file". I'm also pretty sure that the error occurs at TODO 8, where the actual reversing takes place. I use `fseek` to go place each audio block right after the header, which is 44 bytes long. And then I try to write from the buffer of block_size size. Also, after it tells me that phrase, everything basically shuts down. Its starts to say on all of my files, "This editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: unable to read file. The only way to fix this was to reload the page. I'm not sure what causes this, but maybe its going through a loop of some kind? Also, the `WAVHEADER` struct is in a separate file, which is this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t   BYTE;
typedef uint16_t  WORD;
typedef uint32_t  DWORD;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE   chunkID[4];
    DWORD  chunkSize;
    BYTE   format[4];
    BYTE   subchunk1ID[4];
    DWORD  subchunk1Size;
    WORD   audioFormat;
    WORD   numChannels;
    DWORD  sampleRate;
    DWORD  byteRate;
    WORD   blockAlign;
    WORD   bitsPerSample;
    BYTE   subchunk2ID[4];
    DWORD  subchunk2Size;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
WAVHEADER;
```

And if you are wondering, this is Reverse from Pset 4 of cs50x.

Comment: `fread` doesn't return `EOF`, it returns the number if items read. The inside if that loop is wrong too, it always seeks tot he same spot.

Comment: Does CS50 force you to go through all the `fseek()` contortions? Seen loads of these questions. Just read the whole file in first, then reverse it.

Comment: While the other particular elements of the header `struct` each appear twice (once to read, once to write), `header.subchunk2ID` actually appears **4** times... Too much code (making bugs like this invisible) and a weak attempt to address the actual challenge.

Comment: I've changed the loop to check if it's still returning 1 instead of EOF, but still it just says "An error occurred while opening the audio file" So I can't see what happened, or anything happening. The header.subchunk2ID was a typo, so thank you for pointing that out. At least the code stops now to say that.

Answer (score 1):

The previous CS50 assignment was to manipulate data and the solution was to process all of the data in memory. Why not do that here, too?

Following are some 'sketchy' selections of code that might guide you toward writing your own solution.

Load the entire header in one operation (not field by field):

```
    WAVHEADER hdr;
    if( fread( &hdr, sizeof hdr, 1, fp ) != 1 ) {
```

Calculate and allocate a working buffer to hold **all** of the samples

Refer to online doco about WAV files to understand the following calculation

```
    size_t dataSz = hdr.chunkSize + 8 - sizeof hdr;
    uint8_t *p = malloc( dataSz );
```

Load the file's entire data section

```
    if( fread( p, 1, dataSz, fp ) != dataSz ) {
```

The source file can now be closed

Calculate the size of one sample

```
    int smpl_sz = hdr.numChannels * (hdr.bitsPerSample / 8);
```

Use to pointers to iteratively SWAP the first and last samples, then adjust pointers

```
    for( uint8_t *sp = p, *rp = p + dataSz - smpl_sz; rp > sp; sp += smpl_sz, rp -= smpl_sz ) {
        uint8_t tp[32]; // sufficient to handle 2, 4, ... up to (ridiculous) 16 bytes/sample
        memcpy( tp, sp, smpl_sz );
        memcpy( sp, rp, smpl_sz );
        memcpy( rp, tp, smpl_sz );
    }
```

Open the destination file. Write the header , followed by the processed data

Validation of return values left to the reader to complete

```
    fp = fopen( argv[2], "wb" );
    fwrite( &hdr, sizeof hdr, 1, fp ); //  != 1 ) {
    fwrite( p, 1, dataSz, fp );
    fclose( fp );
```

Don't forget to `free()` the allocated memory, then...

```
    return 0;
```

There are a few trivial bits missing, like verifying that the file is a ".WAV" format file and verifying the return value from system calls like `malloc()` and `fwrite()`. These are left as an exercise...

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's a few things I don't understand. What does the second if statement do? I get its to obtain a a variable to store all of the samples, but why do you need an if statement? Can't you just do fread( p, 1, dataSz, fp ); without the if statement? Why do you need to check if its not equal to datasize? Or is p acting like an array, and we are looping until we get all the samples? Then wouldn't we need a while loop? Also, could you break down your for loop? Because I'm not sure what tp, sp, or rp mean or represent.

Comment: Also, could you provide a link to the online doco about wav files?

Comment: @Harr Stack Overflow is a place where people can seek help with specific problems. It is not a free tutorial service to supplement your coursework material. Perhaps you should revisit the lectures and notes to find the answers these questions for yourself.

Comment: I just want to know what's wrong with my code. I feel like you're completely re-writing it, and thats why I don't understand. All I want to know is why my code isn't working, and then what I should do to fix it.

Comment: "_I just want to know what's wrong with my code._" The current version of your code tries to load (and write) each fragment of the `header` struct... Above shows that loading (and writing to the new file) requires only one operation. "_Can't you just do fread( p, 1, dataSz, fp ); without the if statement?_" You can, but you won't know if the file is corrupted. Processing a corrupted file is not good. And, it seems you've not considered what happens with the `fseek()`... How is this "reversing" the audio samples? The outline ("re-write") above comes from a working program. It's up to you, now.